# Javascript UI Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator with a user interface with HTML and Javascript. I've fixed a lot of bugs but there's still issues such as: if the second operator is more than one digit, the answer is wrong, and division doesn't work. I'm fairly new and I know my code is inefficient and 300 lines too long, but could someone humor me and explain my errors?

```js
var resultline_str = " ";
   var multidigit = 0
   var space = 0
   var operating = [];
   
   function type1(){
    resultline_str += " 1";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(1);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '1';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '1';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type2(){
    resultline_str += " 2";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(2);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '2';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '2';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type3(){
    resultline_str += " 3";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(3);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '3';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '3';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type4(){
    resultline_str += " 4";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(4);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '4';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '4';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type5(){
    resultline_str += " 5";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(5);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '5';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '5';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type6(){
    resultline_str += " 6";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(6);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '6';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '6';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type7(){
    resultline_str += " 7";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(7);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '7';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '7';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   
   function type8(){
    resultline_str += " 8";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(8);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '8';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '8';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   function type9(){
    resultline_str += " 9";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if(multidigit === 0){
     operating.push(9);
     multidigit = 1;
    }else{
     if(space === 0){
      var n = operating[0]
      n = operating[0].toString();
      n += '9';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[0] = n;
     }else{
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '9';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
     };
    };
   };
   function type_plus(){
    resultline_str += " +";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('+');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
   
   function type_minus(){
    resultline_str += " -";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('-');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
   
   
   function equals(){
    if(operating.length != 3){
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error';
     multidigit = 0;
     place = 0;
     return;
    }else{
     if(operating[1] === '+'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br/>' + (parseInt(operating[0]) + parseInt(operating[2])) + '<br/>';
     }else if(operating[1] === '-'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br/>' + (parseInt(operating[0]) - parseInt(operating[2])) + '<br/>';
     }else if(operating[1] === '*'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br/>' + (parseInt(operating[0]) * parseInt(operating[2])) + '<br/>';
     }else if(operating[1] === '/'){
      resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br/>' + (parseInt(operating[0]) / parseInt(operating[2])) + '<br/>';
     };
    };
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating = [];
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 0;
   };
   
   function clear_line(){
    resultline_str = " ";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating = [];
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 0;
   };
   
   function times(){
    resultline_str += " *";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('*');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
   
   function divide(){
    resultline_str += " /";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('-');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
   };
```

```css
body{
    background-color:lightblue;
   }
   #head{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:courier;
    border:5px solid grey;
   }
   #grid{
    height:510px;
    width:260px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:10px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    
   }
   td{
    padding:30px;
    font-size:40px;
    size:400%;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
   }
   #result{
    float:right;
    height:525px;
    width:950px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid black;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:strong;
   }
```

```html
<div id="head">
   <h1>Calculator<h1>
  </div>
  <div id="grid">
  
  <!-- calculator buttons -->
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="1" onclick='type1()'>1</td>
    <td id="2" onclick='type2()'>2</td>
    <td id="3" onclick='type3()'>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="4" onclick='type4()'>4</td>
    <td id="5" onclick='type5()'>5</td>
    <td id="6" onclick='type6()'>6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="7" onclick='type7()'>7</td>
    <td id="8" onclick='type8()'>8</td>
    <td id="9" onclick='type9()'>9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="=" onclick='equals()'>=</td>
    <td id="+" onclick='type_plus()'>+</td>
    <td id="-" onclick='type_minus()'>-</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="times" onclick='times()'>X</td>
    <td id="clear" onclick='clear_line()'>C</td>
    <td id="divide" onclick='divide()'>%</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
<div id="result">
  <b></b>
  </div>
```

Comment: Every time you see you're repeating something in your code means you're doing something wrong. I'm referring to your nine `typeX` function which is basically one function taking a single parameter.

Comment: First of all you're repeating the same function every time. I would create a function called type(parameter), so when the user clicks the key two you call the function as follows: type(2). The same applies with the plus, minus, divide and times.

There are lots of errors regarding on global scope, variable protection, among others. Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to pay attention the patterns and then create function that you see repeating. This is the reason why your code is too long. Second you should consider reading about shunting-yard algorithm, this will help you with your issues of the second operand and other things

Comment: What kind of indentation is that?

Comment: Isn't this question apt for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @ManojKumar No, not at all. This question would be closed on Code Review since it contains broken code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start: be careful with the semicolons. JavaScript is quite loose with regards to semicolons and it is quite easy to shoot yourself in the foot with a misplaced or missing one.

As other have told you already (I'm always late, I'm old ;-) ): you have way too much repetitions in your code. You can, for example, make one single function to handle the input buttons. In the HTML

```
<td id="1" onclick='getInput(this)'>1</td>
```

and in the script

```
function getInput(el){
  var value = el.id;
  var num, op;
  num = parseInt(value);
  if(!isNaN(value)){
    // it is a number
    // handle numbers
  } else {
    // it is an operator
    op = value;
    // handle operators
  }
}
```

Or split them in two individual functions for each number and the operators respectively as John Stevens suggested.

But back to your question: why the multidigit numbers do not work. So, let's take it apart:

```
function type9() {
  // we got a digit 9 as a string, concatenate it to the resultstring
  resultline_str += " 9";
  // and "print" it
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
  // the first digit doesn't get any special treatment, just
  // shoved on the stack 
  if (multidigit === 0) {
    operating.push(9);
    // flag that we already have one digit on the stack
    multidigit = 1;
  } else {
    // space is alwys 0, it never gets changed anywhere
    // so only the first branch runs, the "else" is never reached
    if (space === 0) {
      // put the value of the zeroth element of "operating" into n
      var n = operating[0];
      // overwrite(!) that with the zeroth element of "operating"
      // cast to a string
      n = operating[0].toString();
      // concatenate the digit 9 as a string to the end of "n"
      n += '9';
      // make an integer Number out of it
      n = parseInt(n);
      // put that number back to the zeroth place in "operators
      operating[0] = n;
    }
    // there is no "else" hence no second operator, everything
    // get shoved into the first one
    else {
      var n = operating[2]
      n = operating[2].toString();
      n += '9';
      n = parseInt(n);
      operating[2] = n;
    }
  }
}
```

The arithmetic operators

```
  function type_plus() {
    // print the operator
    resultline_str += " +";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    // add the operator to the end of "operating" as a string
    operating.push('+');
    // reset the flag that counts the digits
    multidigit = 0;
    // set "place" to the value 2 as an integer
    place = 2;
  }
```

The actual computing

```
  function equals() {
    // check for errors: always a good idea!
    if (operating.length != 3) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error';
      // reset everything
      multidigit = 0;
      place = 0;
      return;
    } else {
      // iterate over the possible operators
      if (operating[1] === '+') {

        resultline_str = resultline_str + '<br/>' 
              // do the actual addition
              // put it in parenthesis to avoid automatic conversion
              // to a string
              + (parseInt(operating[0]) + parseInt(operating[2])) 
              + '<br/>';
      } else if {
        // let me skip the rest, ok?
      }
    }
    // print the result
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    // reset all variables
    operating = [];
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 0;
  }
```

So, where is that &%$§ bug? You have chosen "space" as the variable to differ between the operators but used "place" instead. Just replace every "space" with "place" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As a good rule of thumb, you should create functions to avoid repetitive code. Your table should look like this, and call the same function for typing a number:

```
<div id="head">
        <h1>Calculator
            <h1>
    </div>
    <div id="grid">

        <!-- calculator buttons -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="1" onclick='typeNumber(1)'>1</td>
                <td id="2" onclick='typeNumber(2)'>2</td>
                <td id="3" onclick='typeNumber(3)'>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="4" onclick='typeNumber(4)'>4</td>
                <td id="5" onclick='typeNumber(5)'>5</td>
                <td id="6" onclick='typeNumber(6)'>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="7" onclick='typeNumber(7)'>7</td>
                <td id="8" onclick='typeNumber(8)'>8</td>
                <td id="9" onclick='typeNumber(9)'>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="=" onclick='equals()'>=</td>
                <td id="+" onclick='type_plus()'>+</td>
                <td id="-" onclick='type_minus()'>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="times" onclick='times()'>X</td>
                <td id="clear" onclick='clear_line()'>C</td>
                <td id="divide" onclick='divide()'>%</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
        <b></b>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the function would look like this:

```
function typeNumber(num) {
    resultline_str += " " + num;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    if (multidigit === 0) {
        operating.push(num);
        multidigit = 1;
    } else {
        if (space === 0) {
            var n = operating[0]
            n = operating[0].toString();
            n += num;
            n = parseInt(n);
            operating[0] = n;
        } else {
            var n = operating[2]
            n = operating[2].toString();
            n += num;
            n = parseInt(n);
            operating[2] = n;
        };
    };
};
```

But, the reason your divide() function isn't working is because you are pushing a minus instead of a divide sign into the operating array. You need to change it to:

```
function divide() {
    resultline_str += " /";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultline_str;
    operating.push('/');
    multidigit = 0;
    place = 2;
};
```